# CMake interface library propagate CXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER

Tags: cmake

I want to have an interface library which propagates `CXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER` to another target.

As I understood the documentation (see below) something like this should work but it doesn't.

```
add_library(lib INTERFACE)
set_property(TARGET lib INTERFACE_CXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER "echo")

add_executable(main) 
target_link_library(main
  INTERFACE lib)
```

but...

```
get_property(_VAR TARGET main PROPERTY CXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER)
message(FATAL_ERROR "compiler launcher: ${_VAR})
```

What am I doing wrong?

[cmake: compatible-interface-properties](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#compatible-interface-properties)

[cmake: transitive-usage-requirements](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#transitive-usage-requirements)

EDIT:
put together a minimal example and added Tsyvarevs hint. Still no success.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)
project(lib)

add_library(lib INTERFACE)

set_target_properties(lib PROPERTIES
    INTERFACE_CXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER "echo 'Hello, World'"
    INTERFACE_C_COMPILER_LAUNCHER "echo 'Hello, World'"
    )

set_property(TARGET lib APPEND PROPERTY COMPATIBLE_INTERFACE_STRING CXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER)
set_property(TARGET lib APPEND PROPERTY COMPATIBLE_INTERFACE_STRING C_COMPILER_LAUNCHER)

add_library(main SHARED)

target_link_libraries(main
    INTERFACE
    lib
    )

get_target_property(_VarMain main CXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER)
get_target_property(_VarLib lib INTERFACE_CXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER)

message(WARNING "varLib: ${_VarLib}")
message(FATAL_ERROR "varMain: ${_VarMain}")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only a property which `INTERFACE_*` counterpart is [listed](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-properties.7.html) as **known** property is propagated out-of-the-box.

For tell CMake to propagate other properties, you need to add those properties into one of `COMPATIBLE_INTERFACE_*` list-like properties. Selection of the list determines how the final value of the consumer's property is selected from its initial value (if it is explicitly set) and propagated values:

- [COMPATIBLE_INTERFACE_BOOL](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/COMPATIBLE_INTERFACE_BOOL.html) requires that all values should be equal as boolean. (E.g. `TRUE` and `ON` are compatible values).
- [COMPATIBLE_INTERFACE_STRING](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/COMPATIBLE_INTERFACE_STRING.html) requires that all values should be equal as string. (E.g. "FOO" and "foo" are incompatible values).
- [COMPATIBLE_INTERFACE_NUMBER_MAX](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/COMPATIBLE_INTERFACE_NUMBER_MAX.html) selects maximum from the numeric values.
- [COMPATIBLE_INTERFACE_NUMBER_MIN](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/COMPATIBLE_INTERFACE_NUMBER_MIN.html) selects minimum from the numeric values.

The other important thing: properties are propagated only at the **end of configuration process**. That is, the propagated value cannot be extracted via `get_property` command. Instead, [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) should be used.

---

While CMake is aware about the property [CXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LANG_COMPILER_LAUNCHER.html), it doesn't know its INTERFACE-prefixed variant `INTERFACE_CXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER`.
Since the property has string semantic, you could add it to the `COMPATIBLE_INTERFACE_STRING` list:

```cmake
set_property(TARGET lib APPEND PROPERTY COMPATIBLE_INTERFACE_STRING CXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER)
```

After that the property will be automatically propagated to the consumers of your library.

For observe the result of the propagation, you could add custom target with `$<TARGET_PROPERTY>` generator expression:

```cmake
add_custom_target(print_prop ALL
  COMMAND echo "Property for main:" $<TARGET_PROPERTY:main,CXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER>
)
```

so building the project (using `make`) will give:

```
Property for main: echo
```

Comment: thanks, is your `set_property` missing a PROPERTY keyword? 
Also I tried your idea and it doesn't seem to work. I've edited my question and added a minimal example. Any suggestions?

Comment: Actually, result of propagation cannot be read with `get_property` command: Propagation occures only at the end of configuration process. I have updated the answer and added corresponding note. Also I fixed the missed PROPERTY in my code.